# Coordinates using idenity matrix won't work

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

Basically i am supplying the vertex shader with an idenify matrix and for some reason it doesn't work.

This is my C++ code:

```
glm::mat4 trans;
GLuint transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "transform");
glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(trans));
```

I am doing this after `glUseProgram()`.

This is my vertex shader code:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 inColor; 
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord; 

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 ourTextCoord;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{   
    gl_Position = transform * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    ourTextCoord = texCoord;
    ourColor = inColor;

};
```

`gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f)` works fine, but multiplying it with the identify matrix doesn't work...

Edit:
All i see is a black screen.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what are you experiencing? Do you see a black screen? Is there an error? Is the shader receiving a different matrix? Please be specific

Comment: I see black screen

Comment: Also i don't get any errors with glGetError().

Comment: [tag:glm] != [tag:glm-math]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of [0.9.9.0](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/releases/tag/0.9.9.0) GLM no longer identity-initializes (or anything-initialize!) default-constructed vectors/matrices by default.

You can `#define GLM_FORCE_CTOR_INIT` before `#include`ing GLM to restore the old behavior.